# Problem working with variant data type w/vba

Tags: arrays, vba, variant

I am trying to learn to use variant data type but facing issues.

```
Public Function z_score(sections As Range, marks As Range) As Variant

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim score() As Variant 'marks range has a few empty cells and error cells as well
                           'hence using variant data type
    
    n = UBound(sections.Value)
    ReDim score(1 To n, 1 To 2)
    score = marks.Value   'assigning marks range values to first column of score

    For i = 1 To n        'adding second column with integer index for calling later
        score(i, 2) = i
    Next i

    z_score = score

End Function
```

I am getting value error instead of nx2 matrix as output.
Can you please help how to resolve the error.
Any help is much appreciated, thanks..

Comment: You need to read up on how redim works.  Your current use is incorrect.  Your first assignment 'score = marks.value' also shows you are not understanding how to assign value to an array in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few areas that could cause this code to fail, I'm afraid:

1. If the passed in range is only 1 cell, the assignment to an array will throw an error.
2. VBA doesn't have a method for copying or cloning arrays, so your code `score = marks.Value` isn't doing what your comments are saying,
3. The `sections` parameter doesn't appear to be doing anything. You are sizing the array against it, but then iterating the `marks` array to assign values.
4. I'm not sure what you want to do with the function, but if it is a UDF called from a worksheet, it would need to be a formula array.

You could adjust your code as follows to have something a little more robust:

```
Public Function z_score(marks As Range) As Variant
    Dim scoreArray() As Variant, marksArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    marksArray = RangeValueToArray(marks)
    
    ReDim scoreArray(1 To UBound(marksArray, 1), 1 To 2)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(marksArray, 1)
        scoreArray(i, 1) = i
        scoreArray(i, 2) = marksArray(i, 1)
    Next
    
    z_score = scoreArray
    
    
End Function

Private Function RangeValueToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim v() As Variant
    
    If rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim v(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        v(1, 1) = rng.Value2
        RangeValueToArray = v
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    v = rng.Value2
    RangeValueToArray = v
End Function
```

Comment: Ambie, thank you for this. 
1. Marks is n x 1 array and will always be that way
2. I was hoping `score = marks.value` works similar to `set score = marks.value` and `score` being a variant i.e. 2D array, it would take values into first column. I am wrong but trying to understand why.
3. This will be part of slightly larger program to calculate section wise average and std deviation of marks. Hence inclusion of section.
4. I am using Office 365 and fortunately Excel auto populates into full array in result. I understand it is a bit lazy.

Comment: Yes, there's no method to copy one dimension of an array in VBA - you have to iterate and assign one value at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem. Assigning values of range to array works but makes the assigned array **two dimensional array but with only 1 column if given range has only one column or row!** So moving the redim with preserve to after assignment line worked for my purpose.

But if one wants to assign values to a column other than first in a 2D array (albeit with 1 column), only solution I am aware of at this point is to do iteration the way Ambie suggested.

```
Public Function z_score(sections As Range, marks As Range) As Variant

Dim score() As Variant 'marks range has a few empty cells and error cells as well
                     'hence using variant data type
Dim n As Integer

n = UBound(sections.Value)

score = marks.Value   'assigning marks range values to first column of score
ReDim Preserve score(1 To n, 1 To 2)

For i = 1 To n        'adding second column with integer index for calling later
    score(i, 2) = i
Next i

z_score = score

End Function
```